# Even with await/async, execution order is not right. Can I do to execute the outer code after inner code finished?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am working in fazerLogin function, inside him is called a function that uses query function. But, it executes first the attribution, I mean before the function has returned with the resultSet. I thought with async/await would solve it, but didn't work. How can I make it work? And, after this how can I redirect from here (below code of redirect also don't work, and there's a routes.js that redirected me to these files).

```
// This is in model file (modelCliente.js)

fazerLogin: async function (entradaJSON) {
    var aux;
    console.log("Encontrado " + entradaJSON);
    dadosJSON = converterParaObjetoJSON(entradaJSON);

    aux = await sql.consultarClienteEmail(dadosJSON);

    console.log("Aux: " + aux); // 1

    applic.post("/login/cliente", function (req, res) {
      var caminho = path.join(__dirname + '/../html/index.html');
      console.log(caminho);
    });

  }
```

```
// Piece of query file (sql.js)

consultarClienteEmail: async function (dadosDeEntrada) { //, callback) {

    var resultSet = JSON.stringify("{}");

    pool.getConnection(function(err, con) {
      if (err) throw err; // not connected!

      comando = "SELECT * FROM cliente WHERE email = " + con.escape(dadosDeEntrada.email);

      // Problema aqui, por que o callback não preenche o resultSet?
      con.query(comando, function (error, results, fields) {
        if (error) throw error;
        // console.log("Cliente consultado!");
        if (results.length) {
          resultSet = JSON.stringify(results[0]);
        }

        console.log("Do SQL:" + resultSet); // 3

        con.release();

        // return await rs;

      });

      console.log("Do ResultSet Retornado: " + resultSet); // 2
      return resultSet;

    });

  }

// The numbers are the orders of execution code is outputing

// Results:

// Aux: undefined //Comment "1"

// Do ResultSet Retornado: "{}" //Comment "2"

// Do SQL:
// {"cpf":"12345678900","email":"d@gmail.com","nome":"DSS",
// "endereco":"Rua So and So, 13",
// "bairro":"some
// neighborhoood","telefone":"1122223333",
// "celular":"11999999999","pendencias":"0","senha":"1234"}
```

Comment: `async/await` works on promises, it doesn't magically work with asynchronous functions that use callbacks. You have to wrap such functions to return a promise instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

welcome to StackOverflow.

As Felix mentioned, async/await works best with Promises.

For functions with callbacks, you would need to wrap it in a promise.

Using your example, it might look like this:

```
consultarClienteEmail: async function (dadosDeEntrada) { //, callback) {

    var resultSet = JSON.stringify("{}");

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      pool.getConnection(function(err, con) {
        if (err) return reject(err); // not connected!

        comando = "SELECT * FROM cliente WHERE email = " + 
con.escape(dadosDeEntrada.email);

        // Problema aqui, por que o callback não preenche o resultSet?
        con.query(comando, function (error, results, fields) {
          if (error) return reject(error);
          // console.log("Cliente consultado!");
          if (results.length) {
            resultSet = JSON.stringify(results[0]);
          }

          console.log("Do SQL:" + resultSet); // 3

          con.release();

          console.log("Do ResultSet Retornado: " + resultSet); // 2
          return resolve(resultSet);
        });
      });
    });
  }
```

Notice this example is wrapping 2 async functions with callbacks in promises. These could also be chained, but either method should work.

Comment: Thanks for this, Matty. Mate, you saved my life! God bless ya. Have a good day.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `await` `pool.getConnection` and make that callback passed to `pool.getConnection` `async` and also `await` `con.query`.

What's happening currently is:

1. `sql.consultarClienteEmail(dadosJSON);` returns nothing, hence `// Aux: undefined`.
2. `pool.getConnection` resolves eventually and logs `// Do ResultSet Retornado: "{}" //Comment "2"`.
3. Then `con.query` resolves eventually and logs `Do SQL: ...` with the result set.

`await` works when the function you are 'awaiting' returns a `Promise`. It then waits for that `Promise` to resolve. So, there are a lot of ways to deal with this in you code. One way is to wrap the body `consultarClienteEmail` in a `Promise` that resolves after the query is returned (@Matty J gives an example of this in their answer).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it was about that Promise, I didn't knew how to use.